# Gutenberg: Error loading block: Invalid parameter(s): attributes but it can be used in the code

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I managed to get an attribute working in my plugin. Well, sort of. I can read and write the attribute props.attributes.content . But I get the message in the Gutenberg block itself:

Error loading block: Invalid parameter(s): attributes

And in the network inspector I see a 400:

data: {status: 400, params: {attributes: "content is not a valid property of Object."}}
params: {attributes: "content is not a valid property of Object."}

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
registerBlockType('simpletoc/toc', {
  title: __('SimpleTOC', 'simpletoc'),
  icon: simpletocicon,
  category: 'layout',
  attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'string',
      source: 'text',
      selector: 'div',
        },
    },
  edit: function(props) {
    props.setAttributes( { content: "newContent" } );
    
    console.info(props.attributes.content);

    const mycontent = props.attributes.content;

    return (
    <div>
    <InspectorControls>
      <ToggleControl
          label={mycontent}
      />
    </InspectorControls>
    <BlockControls>
      <ToolbarGroup>
        <ToolbarButton
          className="components-icon-button components-toolbar__control"
          label={__('Update table of contents', 'simpletoc')}
          onClick={function() {
            sendfakeAttribute(props)
          }}
          icon="update"
        />
      </ToolbarGroup>
  </BlockControls>
  <p className={props.className}>
    <ServerSideRender block={props.name} attributes={props.attributes} />
  </p>
  </div>
    )
  },
  save: props => {
    return null;
  },
});
```

But I can write the attribute with

```
props.setAttributes( { content: "newContent" } );
```

with console.info and my ToggleControl I can actually read the value! What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure there is a defined content attribute at the time of render? You set the attribute in the first line, but that doesn't mean the attribute is instantly updated. It likely means that React will render the component again because the props changed, it may not apply until after rendering. Have you considered setting a default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in question is likely because when you run [`register_block_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/), you didn't set the block attributes or that it (which is an array in PHP) doesn't have the attribute named `content`.

So make sure the attributes are defined in both JavaScript (via `registerBlockType()`) and PHP (via the above-mentioned function), and that the schema is valid. E.g.

- In JS:

  ```js
  registerBlockType( 'simpletoc/toc', {
      attributes: {
          content: {
              type: 'string',
              // other args
          },
          // other attributes
      },
      // ...
  } );
  ```
- In PHP:

  ```php
  register_block_type( 'simpletoc/toc', array(
      'attributes' => array(
          'content' => array(
              'type' => 'string',
              // other args
          ),
          // other attributes
      ),
      // ...
  ) );
  ```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. It worked.